# VIM: How to insert new line and some works in block mode like sublime

Tags: vim

VIM: How to insert new line and some works in block mode like sublime

[image: just like gif]

Comment: To help your googling, the feature is called "Multiple Selections".

Answer (score 0):

Even though there are vim plugins that can make this happen ([see this](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) for an example), I think the "vimiest" way of achieving this result is with vim's macros.

You can find all of vim's macros [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Macros), but basically, you can record a series of keystrokes in memory to execute them later.

In this case, we have a few lines and we want to add a `,` after every line and leave a space after the commas. The keystrokes to achieve that would be:

```
A,<esc>jI<backspace><space>
```

Let's explain this:

- A: go to the end of the line and set insert mode on.
- ,: insert a comma
- :  set normal mode on
- j: go down one line
- I: go to the start of the line and set insert mode on.
- : take the line where you are to the previous line.
- : add a space after the comma.

Now, we need to record these keys in a vim macro. We can do this by pressing `q` and then the key in which we want to record our macro. I usually save it on the same key, so my way of doing this would be to press `qq`. After you press this, you will see something like this at the end of your terminal.

[recording picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0ifj.png)

which means that the recording has started.

> NOTE: Make sure that before you execute this, your cursor is on the first line of the lines that you want to alter.

Now, press the keys in order and when you are done, press the key `q` again to finish the recording.

Finally, now that you have your action recorded you can execute it N times adding a number before the macro. In your case, you have 7 lines minus the line in which you create the macro (that is done already), so six in total. So, if you record your macro in the key `q` and your cursor is in the first line, you can press `@6q` to execute the macro six times.

This is the result:

[recorded result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlz89.gif)

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is really a good solutions for the gif show. much useful for me.